# Why TMDB API Delete List shows an error when i already use the right parameters?

Tags: reactjs, api, postman

so i am using API from themoviedb.org. But i am having some problem here. Is there anyone know why i can't delete the list that i create?

> https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/lists/delete-list

I tried it on postman but im getting this error.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "status_code": 11,
    "status_message": "Internal error: Something went wrong, contact TMDb."
}
```

Comment: Could you share your API request? (E.g. method, path, params; just don't include any sensitive data like api key, maybe fake it) It's pretty hard to figure out what's wrong if you just say it doesn't work.

Comment: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/8220691?api_key=&session_id=81bca85fe3ff9ae74a3251e2e9da481ad4a0f7e4`

Comment: my parameters is session_id & api_key, my path params is list_id

Comment: Just tested list endpoint, had suspicion it could be bad method (`DELETE` needed) or app URL (thought it was there because of CORS policy, but doesn't seems like that), neither of them should be the issue, make sure that you are [generating a session id correctly](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/authentication/how-do-i-generate-a-session-id) and you can see your session id in [active sessions](https://www.themoviedb.org/settings/api/sessions), otherwise you probably should contact TMDB, it could be issue on their side, sorry I didn't helped you much, I hope you will solve it soon anyway!

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to figure it out. I will check more on my typing in the postman and i have contacted the TMDB team, but they havent responded yet.